# Default entry for Selectbox but not present in list

Tags: html, css, forms

Is it possible to have a selectbox that has a default option such as: "Select One" but have the term "Select One" not present in the actual list itself?

```
 <select name="test" id="test">
 <option value="" selected="selected">Select A Entry</option>
 <optgroup label="A Label">
    <option value="one">Option 1</option>
    <option value="two">Option 2</option>
    <option value="three">Option 3</option>
 </optgroup>

    </select>
```

Comment: I don't think you can, only with some exciting and possibly bug prone javascript could this be accomplished.  I'd try to achieve the same goal some other way personally if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go so far as to say no. Personally I would leave it in this list but write a javascript function to validate user input on form submission.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this little bit of Javascript to do the trick:

```
<select name="test" id="test" onclick="this.remove(0);this.onclick=''">
```

As they click the list to select an option, it removes the first option ("Select an Entry" from the list, then clears the event handler so it only does this the first time.